# Using same name for different form fields in same form

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a page that selects records from a fees table, some of the fee items are not optional so i wrote a code to show them as hidden and the optional fee items as checkboxes when a user selects and submits the form, the compute fee gets the selected and hidden fields and adds them to form the total fee to be paid, my problem is when i loop through the arrays of the fee items some fee items repeat themselves. below is the code for the accept-fee.php

```
 <?php 
  if ($row_is_mandatory['mandatory'] =='1') 
    {
       echo '<input name="fee_amount[]" type="hidden" value="'. $row_fee['amount'].'" /> Not Optional'; 
     } 
        elseif ($row_is_mandatory['mandatory'] =='0')
    { echo ' <input name="fee_amount[]" type="checkbox" value="'.$row_fee['amount'].'" />'; } ?>
```

and below is the compute-fee.php code. The problem is there are only twelve entries in the database yet the compute.php displays first the selected items then repeats the first 5 items selected. i know am missing something but i cant just lay my hands on it.

code of interest from compute-fee.php

```
<?php
        if(isset($_POST['fee_amount']))
        {
        $id = $_POST['fee_id'] ;
  foreach ($_POST['fee_amount'] as $key=> $value)
            {
                 echo'   <tr> <td>';
    echo $value;
                echo'   <td>';
    echo $id[$key] ;
                 echo'  </td>       
                 </tr> ';
         }
            }
     ?>
```

Comment: It's probably very annoying by now, but It just has to be said. Drop mysql in favor of mysqli or PDO.

Comment: You can change html source code at client level and change the values of your 'hidden' form attributes. Just saying it's not safe.

Comment: The code is very hard to read especially as it is not really formatted and includes not needed code parts as well.

Comment: @fkerber i apologize for the unclear code below is a simpler shorter version

Comment: @HristoValkanov yes am actually switching to PDO in my recent works just need to correct a minor error in this project.

Comment: @Gudgip how then do i sum and redisplay all the fee items for confirmation before submitting to payment processor.

Comment: @fkerber I have modified the initial post, can you help me out now?

Comment: What do you get when you execute var_dump($_POST); inside compute-fee.php

Comment: when i execute var_dump($_POST); i get double the number of items in the database as the array index. However i was able to use the advise of @Gudgip by executing a different query for the optional fee items and echoing them. In the compute-fee.php i simply queried them again to add to the fee-records table. for now it has solved my problem. Thanks for all of your time